# how can I pass data to my smart contract?

Tags: contract-development, transactions, blockchain, dapps

I have a threshold and some data that must be passed to the smart contract. The smart contract uses this data to make decisions. I'm using web3js. how do I pass this data to the smart contract?

Answer (score 1):

Follow my own example:

**Smart Contract logic:**

Assuming you have a Smart contract with:

1. A global integer variable called globalValue
2. A setter function addInfo(value) -Where value is an integer number.
3. A getter function getInfo()

Like the following, also emitting an event to know when the new value has been set:

**Setter: Set a new value:**

```
uint globalValue;
function addinfo(uint calldata value) public {
   globalValue = value;
   emit NewValue(globalValue);
}
```

**Event to know when the new value has been set:**

Declare the event in your Smart Contract, in order to browser app receive it:

```
event NewValue(
    uint globalValue
);
```

**Getter: Get the new value:**

To verify the proccess, let's assume you have also a getInfo() function:

```
function getInfo() public view returns (uint memory) {
        return globalValue;
    }
```

**Javascript browser app:**

**Init web3**

In your javascript file, for browser app you will have:

```
var myabi = [COPY GENERATED ABI FROM YOUR CODE IN REMIX]
    var contractAddress = '0x7f2cd0448d0a44c4d58a2c9593d6d109a181f023';
            var mySmartContract;
            var miAddress;
    
                function init() {
                    if (typeof window.ethereum !== 'undefined') {
    
                      try {
                        window.ethereum.autoRefreshOnNetworkChange = false;
                      } catch (error) {
                        // User denied account access
                        console.log('User denied web3 access');
                        return;
                      }
                      web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);
                      window.ethereum.enable();
                    }
                    else if (window.web3) {
                      // Deprecated web3 provider
                      web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
                      // no need to ask for permission
                    }
                    else {
                      console.log('No web3 provider detected');
                      return;
                    }
                    initContract();
                  }
    
                  function initContract() {
    
                    mySmartContract = new web3.eth.Contract(myabi,contractAddress);
                    console.log('Contract initialized OK');
                    //console.log(mySmartContract);
    
                  }
    
                  init();
```

**Set the value (JS):**

Once you have initialized web3 and your Smart Contract in browser, call the function:

```
var value = "foo";
mySmartContract.methods.addinfo(value).send({"from":myAddress})
```

Metamask will prompt to ask you for gas and transaction details confirmation.

**Listen to the confirmation event (JS):**

```
mySmartContract.events.NewValue({}, function(error, event) {
        console.log(event);
      })
```

**Get the value (JS):**

If everything goes right, you could verify the value (with no gas needed) with the following function in your browser javascript app:

```
mySmartContract.methods.getInfo().call().then(function(value){
   console.log("The new value is:");
   console.log(value);
});
```

**If you want to wait until an external Smart Contract function is confirmed, try the following (Last line is the KEY):**

```
function _safeTransferFrom(
        IERC20 token,
        address sender,
        address recipient,
        uint amount
    ) private {
        bool sent = token.transferFrom(sender, recipient, amount);
        require(sent, "Token transfer failed");
    }
```

Comment: is it possible to send data asynchronously? I mean, I don't want to ask the result because it might not be ready. I want to receive the data after it has been processed by the smart contract

Comment: Yes sure, with Events. I have updated the initial answer for you to have all implementation details. Enjoy and vote the answer if helpful.

Comment: OK thanks. I have another question. after my contract gets the data, it has to make an asynchronous request to another contract to get information from an external data source (the second contract works as an oracle-> smart contract oracle). I read the answer to this question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55302995/how-to-return-value-to-caller-function-in-asynchronous-javascript-and-web3js), but in my case who calls the 'caller' function that calls 'responder' on the second contract?

Comment: more precisely I want to use the caller function in my smart contract and the responder function in the oracle smart contract

Comment: I read the code more carefully, is there another way to directly return the processed data without calling the get function?

Comment: Inside the Smart Contract you mean? I updated my original answer with a sample function as code example, hope it helps.